# How to send only the id in the @ManyToMany hibernate table?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am creating a website where when users make their profile, they submit the languages that they know. These languages are fetched from a table in the database called languages, which has 2 columns id & name. I used checkboxes to display a list of available languages from database like so...

```
<label for="languages_spoken">Select the languages you can speak in:</label>
<div id="languages_spoken" th:each="language : ${supportedLanguages}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="languagesSpoken" th:value="${language}">
    <label th:text="${language.name}"></label>
</div>
```

Now at the server side I want to store the selected languages into the database in the profile table for the user. So I made a profile @Entity annotated class which has a field for the languages and getter and setters like so:

```
@Entity
public class Profile {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Language> canSpeak;
    ...
    public List<Language> getCanSpeak() {
        return canSpeak;
    }
    public void setCanSpeak(List<Language> canSpeak) {
        this.canSpeak = canSpeak;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now the problem is that, the request that is received by the server has everything as in string format. So in the setCanSpeak(List canSpeak) method, it is recieving an argument of type String[] and thus it is throwing the error

I decided to fix this, that there is no need to send the entire object back as th:value as it will only store the id for the language selected by the user, so I tried this...

```
<label for="languages_spoken">Select the languages you can speak in:</label>
<div id="languages_spoken" th:each="language : ${supportedLanguages}">
     <input type="checkbox" name="languagesSpoken" th:value="${language.id}">
     <label th:text="${language.name}"></label>
</div>
```

and changed the profile entity field from List of Language to List of Integer, since the id of the language is of type Integer.

But then when I added the @ManyToMany annotation to that field, it throwed the exception, as Integer is not an Entity in my project.

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class:
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there's something going on here. The fact that you need to save only an **Integer** doesn't mean you need to change your ***entity model object*** to `List<Integer>`.

You still need to save a ***list of language objects***: `List<Language>`

So, I don't know how you're processing your request, but I'm pretty sure you need to do somenthing like this:

1. Get your data request in your servlet or controller
2. Call your persisting method and create all of the **Language** objects you need setting only the ***ID*** *property of each one*
3. Put all the objects in a `List<Language>`
4. Set that list to your `Profile entity`
5. Persist your profile entity

Maybe a code example would give you a better idea (supose this is your *persisting logic* and **RequestData** is an object with all of the info you need to persist):

> ```
> void persist(RequestData data) {
> ...  
> // you need to persist a Profile, so set all of your info:
> Profile profile = new Profile();
> profile.setX(...);
> profile.setY(...);
>
> // then you need to save languages selected by user only by ID, so:
>
> List<Integer> ids = data.getListOfIds(); // get your data
> List<Language> languages = new ArrayList<Language>(); // create your objects
>
> // create and set a list of languages
> for(Integer i : ids) {
>     Language l = new Language();
>     l.setId(i);
>     languages.add(l);
> }
>
> profile.setLanguages(languages);
>
> // finally persist your profile object using whatever approach you need
> // example: em.save(profile);
> }
> ```